# Find a family of closed sets in $ [0,1]$ such that their union is not closed

Tags: general-topology

I'm starting to see Topology and I have the following problem

Find a family of closed sets in $[0,1]$ such that their union is not closed

For example the sequence of closed sets given by $F_{n}=\left\{\dfrac{1}{n}\right\}$

Is this example true? Why?

Thanks for your help :D

Have a nice day ;)

Comment: If you can find any set that is not closed, that will work, since it is a union of singletons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it’s an example of closed sets in $[0,1]$ whose union is not closed. If $F_n=\left\{\frac1n\right\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then certainly each $F_n$ is a closed set, and

$$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}F_n=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;.$$

For convenience call this set $A$. Clearly $0\notin A$, but you should be able to show that $0$ is a limit point of $A$. A closed set contains all of its limit points, so $A$ is not closed.

Comment: @BrainM.Scott   the best answer , I understood very well :D, thanks for your time and your help :D

Comment: @user63192: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Is that the example you came up with? It works. What is the union of that family of sets? Why is the union not closed? (What is your definition of closed?)

Comment: Thanks, is not closed because 1/n are limits points and  all limits points are in $A=F_n$ (Theorem)

Comment: Not quite. The points $\frac1n$ are isolated in $A=\bigcup_n F_n$ (using Brian's notation). However, $A$ *does* have $0$ as a limit point (its only limit point, actually), and $0$ does not lie in $A$.

Comment: is a convergent series ((1/1),(1/2)......) --> 0